# Alert box when pressing button and there's user input that's not saved

Tags: javascript

I have multiple pages with some input fields. On this page, I have a previous and next button as well as a save (submit) button. When I press the save button, it will save the user input in the database.

However when I press next or previous, I'll get an alert with:**'The user input is not saved yet, untill you click the save button.'** Pressing OK will go to the next page and cancel will make it stay on this page. This is what I want, however the alert will always pop up whenever I press next or previous even when there's no user input or in case of editting the user input has not changed. So I dont want the alert to popup whenever nothing has changed or nothing is filled in.

This is my javascript function:

```
function something(evt) {
        if ( ! confirm("The user input is not saved yet, untill you click the save button.") ) evt.preventDefault();
}
```

buttons:

```
<a onclick="something(event)" href=""> </a>
```

Also on some pages, there are select boxes as well. These have standard values and the select boxes cant be empty so I can't check on the select boxes. The check should only be on textareas and textfield.

I am not able to figure out how to accomplish this.

How would I get to check if the user input(textarea, textfield) has changed or is not empty in my case?

Comment: Use an `onchange` handler in the input fields that sets a variable, and check that variable in `something()`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the close(no sarcasm) That question might help me, but I was wondering how would I get textarea and textfield? *Im not experienced with javascript.*

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yknauggc/1/

Comment: There are several answers in that question that show how to detect changes on text fields.

Answer (score 0):

In the `something()` function do a check if the input field is empty first:

```
function something(evt) {
  var input= document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  if(input && input.value !=""){
    if ( ! confirm("The user input is not saved yet, untill you click the save button.") ) evt.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not an option. I cant do it with ID's or Name's since this function has to be used for multiple pages with different input names

Comment: @Loko. Edited my answer. This time the code checks if at all there is an input present in the page. You can also use `input.length` instead of `[0]` .

Answer (score 0):

you can save your input change in cookies and check them on clicking link whether it is edited or not. Note- include jquery library

```
$('input').change(function(){
 document.cookie="input="+$(this).val();

});
$("a").click(function(e){
    var inputChange= getCookie('input');

    if(inputChange!=$('input').val()){
         var ask = confirm('The user input is not saved yet, untill you click the save button.');
         if(!ask){
             e.preventDefault();
         }
    }

});
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Where are you checking whether there are unsaved changes?

Comment: The OP havenot mentioned use of jQuery. Also you are doing the same thing what OP is doing.